# Possible Problem with Router - occurs during file transfers

Tags: router, wireless-router

With our latest router, we've been having a strange problem. Any time I am downloading a slightly large file or transferring a file from one comptuer to another over our home network, the Internet connection seems to waver. I'm still connected, as I can maintain IM conversations and send emails, but I am unable to browse the Internet. Websites simply will not load.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this could be happening? I'm interested in technical explanations, as I'd be very interested to know what is causing this behind the scenes, but even more interested in layman's terms so I can go about fixing it!

EDIT: Windows 7 is the OS installed on most machines on our home network, with a Windows XP machine and a Windows Server 2008 machine also connected.

The router model is 2701HG-G Gateway and the software version is 5.29.133.27

Sorry about the lack of information, I don't know much about routers so I wasn't sure what to include initially.

Comment: What's the model and firmware version of your router?

Comment: Does the router get hot?  I have seen this with overheating causing lost packets.  This is particilarly common with wifi - are either of the computers wireless?

Comment: Needs more details about the internal networking setup, what operating systems are involved, what the transfer rate is, etc.

Comment: I edited the original post to add more info